# How to write a bash command to open up a kafka producer and immediately follow with topic to create?

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

What's the best way to run the following sequence of commands

```
kafka-console-producer --topic discounts --broker-list localhost:9092 --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=,
profile1,{"profile":"profile1","amount":0.5 }
profile2,{"profile":"profile2","amount":0.25 }
profile3,{"profile":"profile3","amount":0.15 }
exit
kafka-console-producer --topic discount-profiles-by-user --broker-list localhost:9092 --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=,
Daniel,profile1
Riccardo,profile2
exit
...
```

I'm trying to mass create kafka messages for topics without typing line-by-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without typing line-by-line

Create files with the data you want to upload

Then use bash redirection

```
kafka-console-producer \
 --topic discounts \
 --broker-list localhost:9092 \
 --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=, < data.csv
```

If you name the files by the topic name, then you could write a for loop over each file and use that file name as the topic name